# No Implicit Reference Conversion

Tags: c#

I have a public interface which controls if an object which implements it should be visible or not. The basic structure looks like this:

```
public interface IPreviewObject
{
  bool Hidden { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have a class which implements this interface (along with some other interfaces)

```
public abstract class MyParameter<T> : Param<T>, IParameter where T : class, IPreviewObject
{
  protected MyParameter(string name)
    : base(name)
  {
  }
  private bool m_hidden = false;
  public bool Hidden
  {
    get { return m_hidden; }
    set { m_hidden = value; }
  }
}
```

Lastly, I have a second class which inherits from the *MyParameter* class like this:

```
public sealed class MyComponent : MyParameter<SpecialType>
{
  public MyComponent ()
    : base("My Component Name")
  {
  }
}
```

However, I get an error on the definition of my second class *MyComponent* which says **There is no implicit reference conversion from SpecialType to IPreviewObject.** If I remove the *IPreviewObject* from the MyParameter definition, then the same code works fine. But, when I try to add the *IPreviewObject* inheritance, I get this error. Can anyone explain why? Or how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code of `SpecialType`. It looks like that this class does not implement the interface `IPreviewObject` as required.

Comment: `SpecialType` must implement `IPreviewObject` per your where clause definition of `where T : class, IPreviewObject` - if `IPreviewObject` is not a constraint of `T`, then move it up in the definition instead of part of the `where` clause.

Comment: I wanted to move the `IPreviewObject` up to the `MyComponent` level... however, my drawing code which controls whether the object is visible is not is on the `MyParameter` level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecialType should implement interface IPreviewObject

```
public class SpecialType : IPreviewObject
{
    public bool Hidden { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); 
                        set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```